# Cordova JavaScript Plugins

Tags: javascript, plugins, cordova, cordova-3

I am beginning to understand the way Cordova works internally more and more; one thing I continue to struggle with is the format of the JavaScript plugins however.

I am used to writing my JavaScript as follows (which is the standard convention, as far as I am aware):

```
(function () {
    var version = "EXAMPLE",
        v1,
        v2,
        v3
        res;

    function somePrivateFunction(successCallback, errorCallback) {
        someOtherPrivateFunction(sc, ec);
    }

    function someOtherPrivateFunction(successCallback, errorCallback) {
        cordova.exec(sc, ec, 'SomeService', 'SomeMethod', [args]);
    }

    res = {
        VERSION: version,
        doSomething: function (sc, ec) {
            somePrivateFunction(sc, ec);    
        }
    }

    window.myPlugin = res;
}());
```

However, Cordova uses a format I am completely unfamiliar with. I think (and I have only heard of the term here and there) it uses something called `require` (judging by the declarations at the top of most plugins).

The format I often see in the official Cordova plugins are like follows:

```
    var argscheck = require('cordova/argscheck'),
    utils = require('cordova/utils'),
    exec = require('cordova/exec');

var myPlugin = function () {

}

myPlugin.doSomething = function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
    exec(successCallback, errorCallback, 'SomeService', 'SomeMethod', [args]);
}

myPlugin.doSomethingElse = function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
    exec(successCallback, errorCallback, 'SomeService', 'SomeOtherMethod', [args]);
}

modules.export = myPlugin;
```

Maybe it is because I do not have any knowledge on this `require` library - but I do not get it? This seems completely foreign to me, in terms of JavaScript.

What is modules, what is the `cordova/[...]` syntax and what does it indicate. Where are these other cordova modules defined (is that the correct terminology) and where does `modules` come from?

And finally, what does `modules.export` do? I am trying to understand the `<js-module>` tag of `plugin.xml` and the `<clobbers>` tag, but this is holding me back I think.

I understand that when Cordova builds the project, it inserts `cordova.define` surrounding the plugin.

Maybe at least someone can clarify? Thanks!

Comment: the require and exec functions are methods of the cordova object. When you install a plugin it gets wrapped in function that give access to the cordova object. Those calls are actually cordova.require and cordova.exec

Comment: Louis, this doesn't have to do with RequireJS, per my explanation. I have removed the tag

Comment: With the plugin framework, unless you have a specific need, you only need to be concerned with the `exec` command which is the bridge function between js and native code.

Comment: @keldar, no one answered the part of this question about `modules.export` did you ever figure that out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

the require and exec functions are methods of the cordova object. When you install a plugin it gets wrapped in function that give access to the cordova object. Those calls are actually cordova.require and cordova.exec

Here is an example of a plugin js file before and after install:

BEFORE:

```
var exec = require("cordova/exec");

var VideoPlayer = {
    play: function(url) {
        exec(null, null, "VideoPlayer", "playVideo", [url]);
    }
};

module.exports = VideoPlayer;
```

AFTER:

```
cordova.define("com.dawsonloudon.videoplayer.VideoPlayer", function(require, exports, module) {

    var exec = require("cordova/exec");

    var VideoPlayer = {
        play: function(url) {
            exec(null, null, "VideoPlayer", "playVideo", [url]);
        }
    };

    module.exports = VideoPlayer;

});
```

Additionally, to answer about the config setup, the clobbers command secures the name space of your plugin object. From my plugin:

```
<js-module src="www/VideoPlayer.js" name="VideoPlayer">
    <clobbers target="VideoPlayer" />
</js-module>
```

This is stating the name of my JS file, and the object namespace used to call to my plugin in JS.

Comment: Thanks Dawson. If they're methods of the `cordova` object, how do I obtain all other methods (so I can inspect the object, and see what is available)? And is the `[object]/[method]` a `require` syntax?

Comment: Are you familiar with using a web inspector on your projects? If so, in the console you can type 'cordova;' and it will return the entire object for inspection

Comment: Thanks Dawson. Yeah I'm familiar with that, and quite a lot of JavaScript and Cordova. But normal property access in JS is done via `cordova.exec(...)` or `cordova["exec"]`. I've never seen it done via `require("cordova/exec")` and haven't seen this syntax before? That's what I'm struggling to understand.

Comment: As far as I understand, it's part of the new 3.x plugin structure. All plugins are now accessed and loaded through `cordova_plugins.js` instead of the old method of including your plugins js file directly in the `index.html`. Since your plugin js is being loaded and handled via this new method, you are not accessing `cordova.exec` directly as before and instead using the cordova plugin framework to assign exec as a var via the cordova require method.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I am a bit confused here. How come your VideoPlayer module available as a window object and does not require explicit `var VideoPlayer = cordova.require("com.dawsonloudon.videoplayer.VideoPlayer")`. And also, `cordova.require("com.dawsonloudon.videoplayer.VideoPlayer")` not found?